# Javascript Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I've search the forum for why my img is `null` when `getElementById` is called, and I've moved the script below the img, but I am still getting the error that the image is `null`.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img id="irimg" src="ir.bmp" alt="Video Stream" style="width:640px;height:480px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadNextImage() {
    // An image element for loading our next image
    var ourImage = new Image();

    // Setup the event handlers before setting the source
    ourImage.onload = function() {
        // Request the next frame
        requestAnimationFrame(loadNextImage);

        // Swap out the image element on the page with the new one
        var oldImage = document.getElementById('irimg');
        oldImage.parentElement.insertBefore(ourImage, oldImage);
        oldImage.parentElement.removeChild(oldImage);
    };

    ourImage.onerror = function(){
        // Something went wrong with this frame. Skip it and move on.
        requestAnimationFrame(loadNextImage);
    }

    // Finally load the image
    ourImage.src = "ir.bmp?" + new Date().getTime();
};

requestAnimationFrame(loadNextImage);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is occurs here:

```
var oldImage = document.getElementById('irimg');
oldImage.parentElement.insertBefore(ourImage, oldImage);
```

The error given by Chrome is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read Property 'parentElement' of null`.

I'd appreciate help in understanding why it is null. Thanks.

Comment: Using Chome's debug mode (F12), set a breakpoint on the line `oldImage.parentElement.insertBefore(ourImage, oldImage);`, move the cursor on top of `oldImage` and see what is shown (tooltip-style pop).

Comment: It could be that the script is running before the page is fully loaded, meaning the iamge hasn't rendered yet. Normally if you have a script that accesses DOM elements you want to make sure that they have been loaded into the DOM first before you try accessing them. Make your script run once the page has loaded, rather than immediately

Comment: Agree with @Jayce444 as a possible source. Exercising what I suggested may give you some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're removing the image with that ID, and then next time your code comes through it can't find any image with that ID.

You need to set that ID on your new image that you're replacing the old one with.

like so

```
// An image element for loading our next image
var ourImage = new Image();
ourImage.id='irimg';
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lp1724v/